# How to highlight lines on ggplot without losing color coding

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

This question is part R plotting and part graphic design. I am using `ggplot2` to make a scatter plot to compare the 3 different populations. I want to show the **individual points** as well as a **linear regression line**, and they all have to be on the same plot for comparison purposes.

The problem is that the points are very densely plotted and when the regression line is the same color as the points they blend in together and it's very hard to see it. But since some of the populations overlap, if I make the lines all black it is impossible to see which goes with which.

What I would like is a way to highlight the regression line, possibly by outlining it with a black border, or making it a darker shade of the same color, so that it stand out against the background of points. Here's an example below. I've made the points large here to exaggerate the over-plotting, but shrinking them or reducing the alpha isn't going to help (I've tried).

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame('x' = c(rnorm(1000, 1),
                         rnorm(1000, 2),
                         rnorm(1000, 1)),
                 'y' = c(rnorm(1000, 1),
                         rnorm(1000, 2),
                         rnorm(1000, 1)),
                 'z' = factor(c(rep_len(1, 1000),
                                rep_len(2, 1000),
                                rep_len(3, 1000))))

# To make the angle of this line sharp
df$y[2000:3000] <- df$y[2000:3000] + df$x[2000:3000]

ggplot(data = df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = z), size = 3) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y, color = z), method = 'lm', size = 2, fill = NA) +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')
```

EDIT: As per @Gregor's suggestion, plotting a black line underneath the colored ones does what I want but generates an ugly aliasing effect (which is particularly clear with sharply angled lines) which persists no matter the size of the image(see below image). Any suggestions to deal with this, or is it just a specific problem with my system?

[image: Overlapping geom_smooth lines show ugly aliasing effect]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two recommendations you can adjust as you like:

1. Make the points somewhat transparent
2. Highlight the line by plotting a lightly bigger black (or gray) line underneath

Here's the result of a little bit of both. I also reduced the size of the points and lines.

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = z),
             size = 1, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y, group = z),
              color = "black", method = 'lm', size = 1.3, fill = NA) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y, color = z), method = 'lm', size = 1.1, fill = NA) +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')
```

[image]

To deal with aliasing with the overlapping lines, try using the `cairoDevice` package.

Comment: That will depend on lot on your graphics device. You can always bump up the resolution when you save it, and using the `cairoDevice` package makes a world of difference for anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the links will answer better than I can.

You should use `scale_color_manual()` to color the points manually, or within `geom_point()` set alpha = 0.4 or something to make the points transparent. 
http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually

You can also change the shape and size too to distinguish between populations or key individuals within populations as well. http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-point-shapes

As for the line, you can adjust it manually, and use `scale_color_manual()`, `scale_size_manual()`, or `scale_linetype_manual()`.

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-line-types-how-to-change-line-types-of-a-graph-in-r-software#change-manually-the-appearance-of-lines

Comment: I've tried changing the shape and alpha of the points and it doesn't make the plot clearer. Setting the colors manually is an option, but I would rather not lose the ability to color automatically using `scale_color_brewer` if I can avoid it.

Comment: I see. Gregor did as I was thinking and used two lines to pull this off. Have you tried `theme_bw()` as well? That'll get rid of the grey panels in the background.

Comment: No, I haven't. How would that help?

Comment: To me, getting rid of the grey back panels makes the points really stand out. Just tacking it onto gregor's code:   `ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = z),
             size = 1, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y, group = z),
              color = "black", method = 'lm', size = 1.3, fill = NA) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y, color = z), method = 'lm', size = 1.1, fill = NA) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') + theme_bw()` As for getting rid of the alias effect on line 3, I'll give that a closer look tonight!